# I can not solve arrays

Tags: c++

I am new, I am learning to program, especially in c ++. I want to do an exercise that shows the prime numbers between 100 and 200 with arrays and I do not understand why I get an error: "invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript". Help me please.

I tried dev c ++ and compiler online

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    //Define variables 
    int i,j,temp, accountant=0,number = 100;
    bool isPrime = true;

    //algorithm that tells us how many prime numbers there are between 100 and 200

    for(i=100; i<200;i++){
        isPrime=true;

        for(j=2; j<1-i;j++){
            if(i %j==0){
                isPrime=false;
                j=1;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime==true){
            accountant=accountant+1;
        }
    }

    //create the vector primes that have cells
    int vectorPrimes(accountant);

    //filling the vector with the prime numbers between 100 and 200
    for(i=0;i<accountant;i++){
        isPrime=true;
        for(j=2;j<number-1;j++){
            if(number % j == 0){
                isPrime=false;
                j=number;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime== true){
            vectorPrimes[i]=number;
        }
        else{
            i=1-1;
        }
        number=number + 1;
    }

    //Method of ordering the boxes of the arrangement (Major to minor)
    for(i=0;i<accountant-1;i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<accountant;j++){
            if(vectorPrimes[j]>vectorPrimes[i]){
                temp=vectorPrimes[j];
                vectorPrimes[j]=vectorPrimes[i];
                vectorPrimes[i]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    //print the ordered arrangement
    cout<<"The prime numbers between 100 and 200 are the following: \n\n";
    for(i=0;i<accountant;i++){
        cout<<vectorPrimes[i]<<endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The program is too long. Try deleting stuff to show where exactly a problem exists. [mcve]. Make a backup of your code before deleting stuff.

Comment: Closing as typo: `int vectorPrimes(accountant);` should be, assuming the compiler and coding standard allow Variable Length Arrays, `int vectorPrimes[accountant];`. Prefer to use a `std::vector` for this.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few problems.

firstly, you probably want to

```
#include <vector>
```

if you're planning to use `std::vector`.  And secondly

```
int vectorPrimes(accountant);
```

doesn't declare a vector, it declares a single integer.

```
std::vector<int> vectorPrimes(accountant);
```

is most likely what you want.

There may be some other bugs, but if you haven't already done so download a decent IDE for your environment of choice, and learn how to use the debugger to single step through your program.  That will let you see where it's not working as you want it to, hence you can fix the problems.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat good catch - fixed.  I've been burned one too many times by the M.V.P. so I'm a little wary of anything that looks like a function prototype.

Comment: What IDE do you recommend, please?

Comment: That would depend on what Operating system you're using.  For Windows, Visual Studio is one of the best, and the Community Edition is free for personal and educational use.  It does have a bit of a steep learning curve when you first start using it, but stick with it, and it'll start making sense.  For macos either Xcode or Visual Studio Code are viable choices, and there are others.  For Linux I'm not as sure what your options are.  Hopefully a Linux expert will be able to offer some suggestions.